# String padding problem

Tags: c#, string, padding

Using the code given below the padding doesn't seem to be playing as it should, in theory the text **"ADD this text"** should start from column 21 in both the strings but in str2 it has a few extra spaces. On checking the length of both the strings the length turned out to be the same 20 as expected.

```
        string str1 = "Test".PadRight(20);
        string str2 = "Test123".PadRight(20);

        string common = "Add this text";

        MessageBox.Show(str1.Length.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(str2.Length.ToString());

        MessageBox.Show(str1 + common + "\n" + str2 + common);
```

Anybody encountered this problem before? Is there something obvious I am missing.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your MessageBox is showing variable-pitch font?

Try setting the font to `Courier New` (in any relevant control), and see if it helps.

Comment: The same thing happens in a TextBox, TextBlock etc.

Comment: Use fixed-width font (monospaced) in the TextBox, TextBlock, ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
    string str1 = "Test".PadRight(20, 'W');
    string str2 = "Test123".PadRight(20, 'I');
    string common = "Add this text";
    MessageBox.Show(str1.Length.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(str2.Length.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(str1 + common + "\n" + str2 + common);
```

That way you will see if the right number of characters are being padded correctly and you will also be able to tell if it is a font width issue as other have stated.